# Form Requests validation messages by field and not by type

Tags: php, validation, laravel-5

Suppose in a given Form you have two fields of the type `date`: **Birthday** and **Driver License**. Now, I would like to let Laravel handle the validation of the date with the following rules:

```
<?php
public function rules() {
    return [
        'birthday' => 'required|date',
        'driver_license_date' => 'required|date'
    ];
}
```

But I want my custom messages like this:

```
<?php
public function messages() {
    return [
        'birthday.required' => 'Please fill up your birthday',
        'driver_license_date.required' => 
            'Please fill up the date that your Driver License was issued', 
        'birthday.invalid' => 
            'Your birthday date is invalid', // <-- This doesn't work
        'driver_license_date.invalid' => 
            'The date for the driver license provided is invalid', // <-- This doesn't work


        'date' => 'Invalid date', // <-- This works, but its one message for both fields
    ];
}
```

I know about the `:attribute` magic variable and, although this is a fictional scenario case, I have a legit problem where I need to validate two fields of the same type that has nothing to do with each other. I want to be able to provide to my user a message for them and I would need the message to be specific for each field and not generic by the type.

Is it possible to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
public function messages() {
    return [
        'birthday.required' => 'Please fill up your birthday',
        'driver_license_date.required' => 'Please fill up the date that your Driver License was issued', 
        'birthday.date' => 'Your birthday date is invalid',
        'driver_license_date.date' => 'The date for the driver license provided is invalid'
    ];
}
```

Comment: Thank you, the question needs to be 10 minutes old for me to accept the answer.